# 60fps Gifs made with FFmpeg slowed down to 30fps

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gif

I'm currently using the following commands to convert a 60FPS video to a gif yet anything above 30FPS will cause the video to slow down to match 30FPS and just end up making the video longer to keep the same amount of frames. Is there a way around this?

```
ffmpeg -v warning -i "VideoName.mp4" -vf "fps=60,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen" -y "tmp/palette.png"
ffmpeg -v warning -i "VideoName.mp4" -i "tmp/palette.png" -lavfi "fps=60,scale=287:-1:flags=lanczos [x]; [x][1:v] paletteuse" -y OutputGifName.gif
```

I know 30fps is usually enough but there's a flickering element in the video flickering at 60fps so it will either always be present or invisible.

Comment: See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/q/37558504/5726027

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed. 50fps is more than close enough to represent the flickering.